# Mistake in Oriented Minimum Bounding Box Tool?

Tags: qgis, extents, angles

I have used the OMBB (Oriented Minimum Bounding Box) Tool in QGIS to calculate OMBBs around polygons. However, there must be a mistake in the tool as all the yellow boxes in the picture below are calculated to have **angles (= bearing) of around 90 degrees**, but I can tell they have different orientations, and some of them are clearly not oriented in 90 degree direction.

[image]

Some other orientations seem to be calculated correctly - however, sometimes the long and sometimes the short sides of the boxes are used for the orientation/angle.

Any thoughts on how I can make the tool work properly or ideas for other QGIS tools or pyqgis scripts I could use?

Comment: Please clarify. The angles in a box are always 90 degrees but I think that you mean something else. Could you add into your sketch the boxes as you think they are correct?

Comment: @user30184 - edited it - by angle I don't mean the angles in the box, I mean the orientation/bearing of the box as it should be automatically calculated in the "angle" attribute table column that is created by using the OMBB tool.

Comment: What are the layer and the project CRS?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca both WGS84 UTM Zone 43N

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Please, include the necessary details to reproduce it.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca - sorry, not quite sure what details you need. I have a polygon shapefile that represents dunes and was using the OMBB tool to create oriented minimum bounding boxes around the dune polygons. However, the "ANGLE" column in the attribute table does not seem to show correct values as I am trying to show in the picture above. The orientation angle of all yellow boxes is ~90 degrees. But they clearly do not all have a 90 degree bearing. Did you ask me to include data...?

Comment: To start, you can specify the version of QGIS in use. Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification.

Comment: Problem solved! I had used 3.8 previously, and now I tried it with 3.10 and it seems to have worked - not sure if that was the issue, I was trying around lots of things in between... Regarding the problem that for some of the boxes the orientation angle is calculated using the long side, and for some the short side is used: I noticed that whenever in the attribute table the calculated WIDTH > HEIGHT, the short side of the box determines the angle, when WIDTH < HEIGHT the long side determines the angle. So that can be fixed with a tiny field calculator expression.

Comment: Can you provide the field calculator expression